# Excel file creation using php

Tags: php, xml, excel

Hello Friends I am trying to create excel file using php... but its creating problem because of  header("Location: userhome.php") at the end (I need that header to redirect after execution of code) Can you please give me any suggestions; 
Here is my Code:

```
<form method="post" >
    Book title: <input type="text" name="BookTitle" id="name" />
    Book symmary: <textarea name="BookSymmary" id="email" ></textarea>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send Form" />
</form>

    <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $BookTitle = $_POST['BookTitle'];
    $BookSymmary = $_POST['BookSymmary'];
    $filename = 'document_name.xls';

    if ((!empty($BookTitle)) && (!empty($BookSymmary))) {

        header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=" . $filename);

        echo "<html>";
        echo "<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\">";
        echo "<body>";
        ?>
        <div>
            <table>
                <caption>Book printed</caption>               
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Book title</th>
                        <th>Book summary</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $BookTitle ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $BookSymmary ?></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <?php
        echo "</body>";
        echo "</html>";
    } else {
        echo "Please enter something..";
    }
}
 header("Location: userhome.php"); 
?>
```

Comment: Suggestion: Read about it in the manual? What is your concrete programming question? Just a here problem give suggestion does not work very well on Stackoverflow. What prevents you from moving the location header to the top?

Comment: Also you're most like experiencing this: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem - could you please share who had the idea to place the header there at the end ? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) at the end like you're using because there was already an output beforehand. From the documentation:

> Remember that **header()** must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.

If you want to redirect, you can instead output some simple JavaScript:

```
<script>
document.location.href = 'userhome.php';
</script>
```

Comment: Hello Mari.. Thanks for reply but in my case java script is not working.. :(... Is there any other method to create excel  file?

Answer (score 0):

Hello Friends I found solution... may its useful to some one...

```
$sep = "\t";        //tabbed character
$fp = fopen('registrars.xls', "w");

$schema_insert_rows = "";
//printing column names      
    $schema_insert_rows.="Book Name" . $sep;
    $schema_insert_rows.="Book Summary" . $sep;
    $schema_insert_rows.="\n";
    fwrite($fp, $schema_insert_rows);

// printing data:
$schema_insert_rows = "";
    $schema_insert_rows .= "sandy" . $sep;
    $schema_insert_rows .= "Summaaarrryyy" . $sep;
    $schema_insert_rows .= "\n";
    fwrite($fp, $schema_insert_rows);

fclose($fp);
```